# Laravel/Blade forms add 'required' to select element

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I make my select element a required select element?

What I want in HTML :

What I have at the moment in blade:

```
{!! Form::select('someid', [null => 'Please Select'] + $somelist, ['required']) !!}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the 4th argument to select - 'options'

```
public function select($name, $list = [], $selected = null, $options = [])

{!! Form::select('someid', [null => 'Please Select'] + $somelist, null, ['required']) !!}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  It creates an attribute: required="required" instead of simply: required.  Bootstrap appears to want the attribute to be solitary.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Html/FormBuilder.html#method_select), you have missed the 4th parameter:

```
string select( 
    string $name, 
    array $list = array(), 
    string $selected = null, 
    array $options = array()
)

/*
Parameters:
string  $name   
array   $list   
string  $selected   
array   $options    

Return Value:
string
*/

{!! Form::select('someid', [null => 'Please Select'] + $somelist, null, ['required']) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel you don't need to require a field value. For this purpose you will use a request where you can set your rules:

```
public function rules()
    {

        return [
            'name'  => 'required',

        ];
    }
```

If the validation fails than you can not post your form.

It is bad practice to rely  on client-side validation.